# Using SAP HANA CV with Input Parameter in BO Design Studio

Tags: database, hana, business-objects, input-parameters

I wanted to know how can I use a Calculation View that has input parameter (from SAP HANA) as a data source in BO Design Studio.

How will I get prompt for input parameter in Design studio that I create in SAP HANA.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you need exactly, 
e.g. if you have only a single value parameter, and you can make it mandatory, it will pop-up automatically in DS.

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically prompt while you run the report, also you can set default values for input parameters in DS too, go to Application->Showprompts.